# Generic method invokation

Tags: java, generics, method-invocation

If we have generic method

```
class SClass{
    public static <T> ArrayList<T> listFactory(){ return new ArrayList<T>(); }
}
```

we can define type-parameter `T` explicit when this method is calling.

```
SClass.<?>listFactory();//compile error
SClass.<List<?>>listFactory();//ok
```

Why we cant invoke `listFactory` with type parameter `?`, but can with `List<?>`?

Comment: See "Java Generics and Collections" by Naftalin online, p.28-29.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [rules of method invocation are described in the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12). In this case we are interested with

> A method invocation expression is used to invoke a class or instance
> method.
>
> ```
> [...]
> TypeName . NonWildTypeArguments Identifier ( ArgumentListopt )
> ```

`<?>` is a wild type, `<List<?>>` is not.

As for the reason why, consider

```
SClass.<?>listFactory();//compile error
```

What could you even do with `<?>` in `listFactory()`? `?` is unknown. You wouldn't be able to do

```
new ArrayList<?>();
```

because the [JLS prohibits it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9)

> It is a compile-time error if any of the type arguments used in a
> class instance creation expression are wildcard type arguments
> (§4.5.1).

But you couldn't use it with anything else either.

Comment: Thus compiler checked the validity of method invocation after type erasure. Is that right?

Comment: @Dmitrii I don't think type erasure is involved here. The invocation simply isn't syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1):

> Why we cant invoke listFactory with type parameter ?, but can with List?

*Instance Creation* In a class instance creation expression, if the type is a parameterized
type, then none of the type parameters may be wildcards. I think its the same like:

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<?>(); // compile-time error
```

Only top-level parameters in instance creation are prohibited from containing wildcards.
Nested wildcards are permitted. Hence, the following is legal:

```
List<List<?>> lists = new ArrayList<List<?>>(); // ok
```

This is a reason why:

```
SClass.<List<?>>listFactory();//ok
```

### From Java Generics and Collections

> **Generic Method Calls** If a generic method call includes explicit type parameters, those type
>   parameters must not be wildcards.

```
class SClass{
    public static <T> ArrayList<T> listFactory(){ return new ArrayList<T>(); }
}
```

> You may choose for the type parameters to be inferred, or you may pass an explicit type
>   parameter. Both of the following are legal:

```
List<?> list = Lists.factory();
List<?> list = Lists.<Object>factory();
```

> If an explicit type parameter is passed, it must not be a wildcard:

```
List<?> list = Lists.<?>factory(); // compile-time error
```

> Nested wildcards are permitted:

```
List<List<?>> = Lists.<List<?>>factory(); // ok
```

> The Java designers had in mind that every
>   wildcard type is shorthand for some ordinary type, so they believed that ultimately every
>   object should be created with an ordinary type. It is not clear whether this restriction is
>   necessary, but it is unlikely to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `SClass.<?>listFactory()` you can just use:

```
class CompletelyUnrelatedBogusClass { }

SClass.< CompletelyUnrelatedBogusClass >listFactory();
```

Since `?` is unknown, it means it makes no assumptions about what it is. Which means you can put *any reference type* in there, and it would be correct.